# Functional representation of operators in second quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, path-integral, coherent-states

In path integral formalism, the operator $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^\dagger$ represented by numbers $\alpha$ and $\bar{\alpha}$ according to $\hat{a}$|$\alpha$⟩=$\alpha$|$\alpha$⟩ and <$\alpha$|$\hat{a}^\dagger$=<$\alpha$|$\bar{\alpha}$, respectively. Here, |$\alpha$⟩ is the coherent state, say the eigenstate of $\hat{a}$. Based on this logic, the second quantization Hamiltonian $\hat{H}(\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger)$'s functional representation is thus $H(\alpha,\bar{\alpha})$.

However, when including the imaginary time variable $\tau$, in the text book, it seems that the operator $\hat{X}(\hat{a}(\tau),\hat{a}^\dagger(\tau))$ can be automatically represented by $\hat{X}(\alpha(\tau),\bar{\alpha}(\tau))$. I understand that $\hat{X}(\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger)$ $\rightarrow$ $\hat{X}(\alpha,\bar{\alpha})$ is fine and is guaranteed by $\hat{a}$|$\alpha$⟩=$\alpha$|$\alpha$⟩.

Can someone tell me why $\hat{X}(\hat{a}(\tau),\hat{a}^\dagger(\tau))$ $\rightarrow$ $\hat{X}(\alpha(\tau),\bar{\alpha}(\tau))$ is also valid? I am confused at this point because to me the $\hat{a}(\tau)$|$\alpha(\tau)$⟩=$\alpha(\tau)$|$\alpha(\tau)$⟩ is not at all obvious.

Comment: Sorry, it should be a^dagger. I have changed it.

Comment: Now it is unambiguous, but quite wrong/nonsensical. You probably should use $\langle \alpha|\hat a^\dagger= \langle \alpha |\bar{\alpha}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have corrected that. Do you have an idea about how to arrive at $\hat{X}(\alpha(\tau),\bar{\alpha}(\tau))$ for the imaginary-time dependent case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the reality or not of time is meaning to you--you never revealed your text.

Given the standard coherent states, $\hat{a}$|$\alpha$⟩=$\alpha$|$\alpha$⟩ and <$\alpha$|$\hat{a}^\dagger$=<$\alpha$|$\bar{\alpha}$, if you hamiltonian is standard ordered, i.e. with all annihilators to the right of creators, obviously
$$
\langle \alpha|  {H}(\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger)|\alpha\rangle=  H(\alpha,\bar{\alpha}).
$$

In the Heisenberg picture, $ \hat a(t)  =e^{-i\omega t}\hat a ~~~\leadsto$
$$
\hat a(t)|\alpha\rangle =e^{-i\omega t}\hat a|\alpha\rangle= e^{-i\omega t}  \alpha|\alpha\rangle\equiv \alpha (t) |\alpha\rangle .
$$
In the Schrödinger picture,  $\hat a|\alpha(t)\rangle=\alpha(t)|\alpha(t)\rangle$, amounts to the same eigenvalue equation as above, with the suitable redefinitions!
We then have
$$
\langle \alpha (t)|  {H}(\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger)|\alpha(t)\rangle=  H(\alpha (t),\bar{\alpha}(t)).
$$
Again in the Schrödinger picture, by the same token,
$$
\hat X=(\hat a + \hat a^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}, ~~~\leadsto \\
\langle \alpha (t)|  \hat X |\alpha(t)\rangle=  (\alpha (t)+\bar{\alpha}(t))/\sqrt{2}.
$$
I'm not sure where the imaginary or real time would  enter here.